# changing the color of card in material ui conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```js
const styles = {
  card: {
    minWidth: 240,
    color: 'green'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10
  }

};

function handleToggle(colorDecider) {
  if (colorDecider)
    styles.card.color = 'blue';
  else
    styles.card.color = 'red';
}
```

Here, I am trying to change the color of the card using `handleToggle` function based  on the value of `colorDecider`. But the code doesn't change. Yet I have checked the `styles.card.color` using `console.log`, changed color is printed in the `console`. But, color doesn't actually change in the card

Comment: How are you callinng the function?

Comment: the function is being called on passing data from parent to child. Do not worry about the function call. It's properly done. Plz tell me how do I get access to change the color of the card rather than chaning manually in color : ' '. is there any inbuilt function for that?

Comment: It's an object. The only way to change it is by using the way you currently did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a property somewhere in an object does not magically rerender the related parts of the page. If you need something stateful, move it into the related conponent's state:

```
 class Colorful extends React.Component {
  constructor(...props) {
   super(...props);
   this.state = { color: "red" };
  }

  changeColor(color) { this.setState({ color }); }

  render() {
   return <div 
     style={{ color: this.state.color }}
     onClick={() => this.changeColor("blue")}
  >Click me!</div>;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @jonaswilms but might add that you can also force an update like this:

```
function handleToggle(colorDecider) {
  if (colorDecider)
    styles.card.color = 'blue';
  else
    styles.card.color = 'red';
  this.forceUpdate(); // force rerender
}
```

The above assumes, of course that you have bound the right `this` value e.g.

```
<div onClick={handleToggle.bind(this)} />
```